# Convert a HTML page to PDF using HTML5 Blob object

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

How can i convert a html to pdf using HTML5.

What i have tried till now is

```
var self = this;
      self.pdfName = 'fullrecord.pdf';
      var blob = new Blob([self.htmlcontent], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      self.pdfurl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      window.open(self.pdfurl);
```

The problem is, I always get a blank pdf.

Comment: To what refers `this`, What does `self.htmlcontent` contains?

Comment: converting an html document to a pdf file is a little bit more complicated than changing its header to `application/pdf`. I don't know any good solution for this but you may try [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) library

Comment: this refers to the current context, and self.htmlcontent is a variable where i have kept the html string

Comment: @Kaiido,  I am already trying with jspdf, it works fine, but its not consistent, and breaks in some cases.. any other library suggestion

Comment: Sadly no... As I said, "I don't know any good solution for this", and what I meant was that yes, jsPDF is not consistent and kind of an harsh to use... But for sure, you were full of hope with your solution (like if you tried to convert it to `video/mp4`)

Comment: Oh and if it's for your personal use (not your website's users) Adobe does provide browser extensions with Acrobat XI. Hopefully it will be more consistent than jsPDF's labyrinthine system